# In wpf how to handle a event raised by a button inside user control in the page which uses that user control

Tags: wpf, mvvm, event-handling, wpf-controls

I am using MVVM architecture. I had created a user control which contains a button control.
I want the click event of the button control to be captured in page which uses this user control. How to do this? Plase help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A button has a Command property. You should use that instead of the Click event by binding to an ICommand exposed by your ViewModel.

EDIT:

Two possibilities:

1) MVVM-way: Have a property for the command on your UserControl's ViewModel which you then set from your using page's ViewModel.

2) Non-MVVM way (although you could combine this with 1): Have a dependency property on your UserControl for the command, which you bind to in your UserControl's XAML. You can then bind to this dependency property from the using page.

Comment: How could I make ICommand to call a method in the page which uses this user control?

Answer (score 3):

You can define the event on a higher parent control:

Normally you would have:

```
<Grid>
      <Button Click="SomeMagicalEventHandler" />
</Grid>
```

But you can also define the event on the Grid as follows:

```
<Grid Button.Click="SomeMagicalEventHandler">
      <Button />
</Grid>
```

Of course, as long as its not handled in your event handler (`arguments.Handled = true;`) it will bubble upwards your visual tree until it reaches your page!

Hope this helps!